# Does Brian Ballsun-Stanton have a book published yet?

Tags: discussion

No, really. Each post of his is like a tiny lecture by my statistics professor. A tour-de-force on the philosophy of game-making by Brian Ballsun-Stanton would be informative to read.

So come on dude, who's your publisher?

Comment: Err... what? Are you serious?

Comment: LOL! Wow! Has Philip just won rpg.se?

Comment: lol no book yet. but he is a doctor now :).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No<sup>*</sup>, I don't, cause I like eating ... and paying rent.**

At present, I can't afford to take the month or two to write a book on the philosophy of role-playing. While I just got my doctorate, I'm trying to find a job at various universities. On the other hand, if there's some level of community funding, I'd be willing to start a kickstarter to cover rent and ... whatnot to...

... what? I.. really? ...

A book is 50k-100k. I'll fold in my two papers on RPs for a clean 10k, that leaves us 40k short. Structuring 2-4k per answer for 10 selected answers could work, leaving me to write framework, structure, question and answer amplification, and a lit review of doom. (and yeah, wading through the IJRP.)

I can probably do this in 1-2 months part time.  (hahahaha... ::sigh:: I could, actually. I even have editors.)

But I can't afford to right now.

As I said at the start, if there's community support via kickstarter, I'd love to. Or, if you know of any agencies willing to write a grant, I'm more than willing to write.

### Edit:

Doing some simple <sup>**</sup> analysis of my RPG.SE posts, I've got 152k words on here. Easily enough to make a book with sufficient editing and framing. Call it a month of work?

[image: my most common 150 words]

<sup>*</sup> Does a thesis count? What about 2 working papers on RPGs? ([Here.](http://www.drbbs.org/))

Comment: Completely serious. A kickstarter is a good idea. When you have a spare month or two, let us know. I could chuck in a couple hundred to get the ball rolling. Any more and I'd have to get approval from the boss. Personally, I wouldn't be in for more than a grand though. While I like your material, I don't like it any more than that.

Comment: Oookay. Well, I'll look into academic publishers and think up a ToC and we'll go from there.

Comment: I think we just need to get Brian a job at wizards so he can help keep the games awesome.

Comment: @philip on a serious note, are you looking for a collected essays with amplification or philosophy book?

Comment: A philosophy of game-making and game-running. Honestly, I'm looking for a rant about how things ought to be done. From most people that would be an absolute bore, but you seem to hold yourself to a pretty high standard. (Wasn't aware of your working papers, neat. Haven't had time to sit down with them yet)

Comment: One Class Power - Character Level Damage will be my imaginary band name and first album.

Comment: I would be interested if a kickstarter campaign is started. I'm not about to promise a couple of hundred like philip, but I could contribute the average price for a book in a heartbeat...